# Plotting every second data point in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
Data <- data.frame(
    week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
    variable = c("nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "nuclear", "atomic", "atomic", "atomic", "atomic", "unemployment", "unemployment", "unemployment", "unemployment"),
    value = c(2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5, 1)
)
```

I need a black-white-graph. So I use the following code:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(week, value, group=variable)) + xlab("Year") + ylab("Frequency of searches") +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=variable))+ # Line type depends on cond
  geom_point(aes(shape=variable))+  # Shape depends on cond
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(0,1,2)) + # Change shapes
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dotted", "dotdash"))+
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.title=element_blank(), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#FFFFFF", colour="#000000"))+
  stat_smooth(method="loess"))
```

That works for fine for this small dataset. But when it's bigger, it's difficult to distinguish the lines and points from each other. It all looks very similar. Is there a way to plot only every second or tenth data point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subset `Data` using `seq()`:

```
Data[seq(1, nrow(Data), 4), ] # every 4th row
Data[seq(1, nrow(Data), 2), ] # every 2nd row
# ...
```

Comment: Hi, Please also tell on how to make sure that we are taking the last point in the plot. Here we are taking the first point.

Answer (score 7):

You can override the data for `geom_point` with a subset:

```
geom_point(aes(shape=variable), data=subset(Data, week %% 2 == 1))
```

Comment: oh, that's great. Thank you. But what if "week" has date as class - like "2004-01-04"

Comment: Perhaps `(as.numeric(x)/24/3600) %% 2 == 1`. Look at package `lubridate` for easy date manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to take the even rows, relying on recycling of the index vector:

```
Data[c(FALSE,TRUE),]
```

And every 10th:

```
Data[c(rep(FALSE, 9), TRUE),]
```

Comment: Nice trick, but I wouldn't rely on the order of the data frame, especially with multiple factor variables.